# Ember sending query params fails

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I am trying to pass a param in my path. i try like this:

route.js

```
this.route`enter code here`('purchase', {path: '/purchase'}, function () {
        this.route('purchaseDetails');
        this.route('purchaseEdit', {path:'purchaseEdit?country='}); //showing in the URL
        this.route('purchaseReview');
        this.route('purchaseConfirmation');
      });
```

redirecting like :

```
this.transitionTo('purchase.purchaseEdit', "SG");
```

But not works. any one correct me please?

Answer (score 1):

It's explained very well [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/routing/query-params/).

You can also do like this. The url will be shown as `.../purchase/purchaseEdit/India`

```
this.route('purchase', {path: '/purchase'}, function () {
    this.route('purchaseDetails');
    this.route('purchaseEdit', {path:'purchaseEdit/:country'}); //showing in the URL
    this.route('purchaseReview');
    this.route('purchaseConfirmation');
  });
```

In the route of `purchaseEdit`, while getting the `model` you can get the value of the country.

```
model:function(params)
{   
    console.log(params); //Contains the dynamic-params declared in the route as object.
    return this.store.find('purchasedItem',params.country).then(function(response){
                return response;
    },function(response){
                return "";
    });
}
```

Comment: Just note - find is deprecated now.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was using 2.12 version in our project. Just to show the use case and to access the dynamic param, I gave an instance of `model` method. Thank for indicating that :)